# Solving for an unknown function

Tags: calculus, functions, exponential-function, partial-derivative

I'm having trouble with the mathematical aspect of a journal article I'm researching. I need to figure out how the equation in the curly brackets in [Vref](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prIrM.jpg) turned into an exponential function in [Id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKJLP.jpg). 
 
 Basically the article states that the terms in the curly brackets should be constant with variable T. I have checked that it is true: 
 
 $ln(f(T)) + \frac{T}{f(T)} \frac{\partial}{\partial T}(f(T))=\frac{A}{C}$ (1) 
 
 where 
 
 $f(T)=exp(\frac{AT+B}{CT})$ (2) 
 and A, B and C are constants. 
 
 But the question I like to ask is how to get (2) from  (1). If anyone can give a reference for this or a guide, I'm extremely greatful. 
 
 **If you're interested in the article:** 
 L. Magnelli, F. Crupi, P. Corsonello, C. Pace, G. Iannaccone, "A 2.6 nW, 0.45 V Temperature-Compensated  Subthreshold CMOS Voltage Reference," *IEEE J. Solid-State Circuits*, vol. 46, no. 2, pp. 465-474, Feb. 2011.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to solve the differential equation

$$\ln(f) + \dfrac{T}{f} \dfrac{df}{dT} = \frac{A}{C}$$

This is a separable differential equation: rewrite it as

$$ \dfrac{df}{f (A/C - \ln f)} = \dfrac{dT}{T} $$

and integrate both sides, then solve for $f$.

Answer (score 0):

Define a function
$$
f(T) = \exp{\left(\frac{AT + B}{CT} \right)}
$$
Its derivative is, by the chain rule
$$
f'(T) = \exp{\left(\frac{AT + B}{CT} \right)} \frac{\partial }{\partial T} \left( \frac{AT + B}{CT} \right) = \exp{\left(\frac{AT + B}{CT} \right)} \frac{A}{CT}
$$
Now the first equation is
$$
\begin{split}
\ln{f(T)} + \frac{T}{f(T)}f'(T) =& \frac{AT + B}{CT} + \frac{T}{\exp{\left(\frac{AT + B}{CT} \right)}}\exp{\left(\frac{AT + B}{CT} \right)} \frac{A}{CT}\\
=& \frac{AT + B}{CT} + \frac{TA}{CT}\\
=& \frac{2AT + B}{CT} = \frac{AT + B}{CT} + \frac{A}{C}\\
\end{split}
$$
This result is not exactly the answer we're looking for ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to solve $$\ln(f) +T\dfrac{ f'}{f}  = \frac{A}{C}$$ Let  $f=e^g$ to make 
$$g+T g'= \frac{A}{C} \implies (Tg)'=\frac{A}{C}\implies Tg=???\implies g=???\implies f=???$$